# Running javascript code in the background even when tab is closed

Tags: javascript

I want to keep a session with every website Iam trying to connect to 
SO my Solution to this problem is to send http request  to every website I want to keep my session with

```
function keep_alive() {
    http_request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    http_request.open('GET', "");
    http_request.send(null);
};

setInterval(keep_alive,10000);
```

the problem is when i close the tab 
the javascript code execution will stop in that tab and i will lost my session after a timeout limit

Edit1

What I'am trying to achieve here is to keep an open connection through poxy 
the problem with this proxy is that some times when I'am trying to make a request I get request failed Like this picture

[failed connection is in red and successful connection is in black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQGcP.jpg)

So When I managed to open a certain website after several attempts 
I need to keep my session with this website alive as long as possible 
even when I am idle 
Like this picture

[session time with different websites and the longest connection is a vpn connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tUpdo.jpg)

The only solution i came up with so far is to use vpn 
but Iam seeking for another solution

Comment: You cannot. Highest scope is window. When you close tab, this window is cleaned by GC and hence all your code is gone. Also why do you wish to do this?

Comment: And you probably can't make those requests anyway due to CORS restrictions. Really not clear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem: http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Thankfully when you close a tab, everything linked to it goes away. The only other option are Service Workers which can do work in the background, but their scope is very limited, and most certainly won't allow you do the that. But what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: @Medo Sayed, if this was possible, this could have posed big security risk as anyone could create a `key logger`.

Comment: @Rajesh not possible to call your own api with another site's session cookies

Comment: @charlietfl my bad. :-p

Comment: I don't think he wants to call his own API; I think that for some reason his cookies keep getting deleted or whatever, and he's tired of having to login over and over again, maybe?